# Sklearn and Sparse Matrices ValueError

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm aware similar questions have been asked before, and I've tried everything suggested in them, but I'm still stumped. I have a dataset with 2 columns: The first with vectors representing words stored as a 1x10000 sparse csr matrix (so a matrix in each cell), and the second contains integer ratings which I will use for classification. When I run the following code

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row)
    print(row[0].shape)
```

I get the correct output for all the rows

```
Name: 0, dtype: object
(1, 10000)
Vector      (0, 0)\t1.0\n  (0, 1)\t1.0\n  (0, 2)\t1.0\n ...
Rating                                                    5
```

Now when I try passing my data in any SKlearn classifier like so:

```
uniform_random_classifier = DummyClassifier(strategy='uniform')
uniform_random_classifier.fit(data["Vectors"], data["Ratings"])
```

I get the following error:

```
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
     ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What am I doing wrong? I've made sure all my sparse matrices are the same size and I've tried reshaping my data in various ways, but with no luck, and the Sklearn classifiers are supposed to be able to deal with csr matrices.

**Update**: Converting the entire "Vectors" column into one large 2-D matrix did the trick, but for completeness sake the following is the code I used to generate my dataframe if anyone is curious and wants to try solving the original issue. Assume *data* is a pandas dataframe with rows that look like

"560 420 222"  5.0

"2345 2344 2344 5"  3.0

```
def vectorize(feature, size):

"""Given a numeric string generated from a vocabulary table return a binary vector representation of
 each feature"""

vector = sparse.lil_matrix((1, size))

for number in feature.split(' '):
    try:
        vector[0, int(number) - 1] = 1
    except ValueError:
        pass

return vector

def vectorize_dataset(data, vectorize, size):

"""Given a dataset in the appropriate "num num num..." format, a specific vectorization format, and a vector size,
returns the dataset in vectorized form"""

result_data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(data.shape[0]), columns=["Vector", "Rating"])

for index, row in data.iterrows():

    # All the mixing up of decodings and encoding has made it so that Pandas incorrectly parses EOF chars
    if type(row[0]) == type('str'):
        result_data.iat[index, 0] = vectorize(row[0], size).tocsr()
        result_data.iat[index, 1] = data.loc[index][1]

return result_data
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible code snippet here.

Comment: *"... a matrix in each cell..."*  That is a nonstandard use of a sparse matrix.  I suspect you'll have to flatten your data structure to use a plain 2D matrix, where each element in the matrix is a scalar.

Comment: I had an issue with an `sparse` matrix a few days ago and solved it by transforming it into a `dense` matrix. If it is viable for you, it is an easy solution.

Comment: Show us how you constructed the sparse matrix.  A `csr` matrix can only do math with a simple numeric `dtype`.  Anything else will give problems at some point or other.

Comment: Yup it's as you said Warren Weckesser, it worked when I turned the vectors into a single 2-D X*10000 sparse matrix. For completeness sake I'll update how I generated my data and see if anyone knows how to solve the original problem